# How to enable the maximize button in the gui?

Tags: autohotkey

When i create a GUI her maximize button is grayed out/disabled, how can i enable it?

Example:

```
Gui, Add, Button, w100 h30, Button
Gui, Show, w400 h300
```

I was reading the docs and found this parameter `Maximize: Maximizes and activates the window.`

It does maximize the GUI as soon its launched:

```
Gui, Show, Maximize w400 h300
```

However, i would like to enable maximizing/restoring upon clicking the maximize button.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the flag `+Resize`

From [docs](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Gui.htm):

> Resize: Makes the window resizable and enables its maximize button in the title bar. To avoid enabling the maximize button, specify +Resize -MaximizeBox.